# cannot find the match() from <div> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have question in JavaScript, I'm quite new so be easy on me please :) .

Let's say I have this HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="myDivId"> <h3> <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://google.com"><strong>TEXT Number 453</strong></a></p></h3></div>
</body>
```

and when I write to extract the digits only:

`var x = document.getElementById("myDivId").innerHTML;`

`var patt1=/\d{3}/gi;`

`document.write(x.match(patt1));`

The Output will be

`NaN` not the number `453`, but when I remove all the attributes like (hyperlink syntax,

syntax, etc) it does work.

I know I'm doing a mistake, so I hope you enlighten me :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. I was using `getElementById()` and inside my `DIV` I have a hyperlink `<a>` in which the link contained digits, that's why `regexp` was pulling the `NaN` error.  To solve it I used/learned `getElementByTag()` and tagged my sentence to avoid the hyperlink code.  That fixed the problem :) Thanks, guys!

Comment: +1 Solved your own problem and then documented it. Everyone wins.

Comment: Yes. You should see an empty checkmark under your answer. Go ahead and click it.

Comment: I have to wait 11 hours to click it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the d character to represent a digit as below:

```
var patt1=/\d{3}/gi;
```

Otherwise your regular expression will be looking for three occurences of the 'd' character

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put the escape \ when I wrote it here. But I have it written with \ when I tested it and I still get the result `NaN`

Comment: I solved the issue. I was using `getElementById` and inside my `DIV` I have a hyperlink which contain numbers, so `regexp` was pulling the `NaN` error.  to solve this issue I used/learned `getElementByTag()`  and tagged my sentence to avoid the hyperlink code and it fixed the problem :) thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this script,

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDivId").innerHTML;
var patt1=/\d{3}/gi;
document.write(x.match(patt1));
```

added '\' in the regx.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put the escape symbol when I wrote it here. But I have it written with \ when I tested it and I still get the result `NaN`

Comment: I have tested the above code. It is working for me. 453 got displayed in the screen. Browsers used: IE8 and FF3. Could you verify once?

Comment: I solved the issue. I was using `getElementById` and inside my `DIV` I have a hyperlink which contain numbers, so `regexp` was pulling the `NaN` error.  to solve this issue I used/learned `getElementByTag()`  and tagged my sentence to avoid the hyperlink code and it fixed the problem :) thanks man!